# Solana-Test-Validator not working

Tags: solana-test-validator

I am currently trying to learn the basics of Solana Smart Contracts and therefore tried the [hello world program](https://github.com/solana-labs/example-helloworld/tree/master). Because I am on Windows, I downloaded Ubuntu on WSL 2. I downloaded Solana-CLI v1.14.18 (also tried with the stable version v1.13.8), had git(v2.34.1) and node (v9.5.0) already installed and created a new directory I just called "Rust". There I cloned the project with `git clone ...`.

I stepped in the directory and am now at `jmv@JMV_Legion:~/Rust/example-helloworld`. But now trying to run `solana-test-validator` doesn't work but instead exits with the log (took it from the validator.log):

```
[2023-05-22T21:29:34.129159283Z INFO  solana_test_validator] solana-validator 1.13.8 (src:43daa379; feat:1775889670)
[2023-05-22T21:29:34.129189090Z INFO  solana_test_validator] Starting validator with: ArgsOs {
        inner: [
            "solana-test-validator",
        ],
    }
[2023-05-22T21:29:34.129214568Z WARN  solana_perf] CUDA is disabled
[2023-05-22T21:29:34.129226601Z INFO  solana_perf] AVX detected
[2023-05-22T21:29:34.129229466Z INFO  solana_perf] AVX2 detected
[2023-05-22T21:29:34.133541082Z INFO  solana_faucet::faucet] Faucet started. Listening on: 0.0.0.0:9900
[2023-05-22T21:29:34.133557854Z INFO  solana_faucet::faucet] Faucet account address: 7FmdVRjCXFm7z7znSgbmPQrgRQCko7WA2YupQfVEHGrc
[2023-05-22T21:29:34.141941064Z INFO  solana_ledger::blockstore] Maximum open file descriptors: 500000
[2023-05-22T21:29:34.141968907Z INFO  solana_ledger::blockstore] Opening database at "test-ledger/rocksdb"
[2023-05-22T21:29:34.744682542Z INFO  solana_ledger::blockstore] "test-ledger/rocksdb" open took 602ms
[2023-05-22T21:29:34.749639465Z INFO  solana_metrics::metrics] metrics disabled: SOLANA_METRICS_CONFIG: environment variable not found
[2023-05-22T21:29:34.750927182Z INFO  solana_metrics::metrics] datapoint: shred_insert_is_full total_time_ms=0i slot=0i last_index=2i num_repaired=0i num_recovered=0i
[2023-05-22T21:29:35.040554913Z ERROR solana_ledger::blockstore] tar stdout:
[2023-05-22T21:29:35.040589949Z ERROR solana_ledger::blockstore] tar stderr: /bin/sh: 1: bzip2: Permission denied
    tar: test-ledger/genesis.tar.bz2: Wrote only 4096 of 10240 bytes
    tar: Child returned status 127
    tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

What do I need to do to solve this? I really would like to start but nothing has worked yet and I really am not experienced in Linux at all.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After re-downloading WSL, Solana, Rust and everything I found out that in WSL/Linux I need to go to the base root to have it executed.

So I hit `cd ~` and then `solana-test-validator`just worked. I hope this will help someone who faces the same problems in the future!